# Sum of the reciprocal of ec exponents leading to a probable prime

Tags: number-theory

Ec primes are primes of the form:

$(2^n-1)\cdot 10^d+2^{n-1}-1$ where d Is the Number of decimal digits of $2^{n-1}$.
The n's leading to a prime or probable prime are present in this vector:

[2,3,4,7,8,12,19,22,36,46,51,67,79,215,359,394,451,1323,2131,3336,3371,6231,19179,39699,51456,56238,69660,75894,79798,92020,174968,176006,181015,285019,331259,360787,366770,...,541456]

There could be exponents leading to a prime between 366770 and 541456 missing. Moreover for exponents greater than $10^5$ there Is no doublecheck and so It could be that some other exponent Is missing.

Anyway the sum of the reciprocals of the exponents leading to a prime or probable prime comes close to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, which Is the famous value of the Basel problem. The sum Is equal to $1.643688...$

Considering that exponents leading to a prime become sparser and sparser, Is It possible that the sum equals exactly $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$? And Is this another coincidence?

Comment: We won't reach $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ , but this is really close.